# selective clearing float items in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-float, internet-explorer-7

I have a list of 5 items which are floated left, and displayed inline.
on the 4rd item, I set clear left, thereby causing the 4th item into a new line.

But in IE7 the 5th item floats next to the 3rd item on the first line instead of floating next to the 4th item on the new line. Any ideas how to get this to work for IE7?

jsfiddle.net/3dSsP/4/

Comment: Came across the same problem recently and gave up on it, figuring that few people use IE7 and for me it was only a minor issue anyway.  I would be keen to hear of a solution.  Googling this problem is difficult because most of the results are about how to contain floats in a container, a much more common problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3dSsP/8/  updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come across this many times and unfortunately the only solution i'm aware of is to have a seperate clearing element to clear the float.

It's ugly but it works:

```
<ul>
  <li>List 1</li>
  <li>List 2</li>
  <li>List 3</li>
  <li class="clear">&nbsp;</li>
  <li>List 4</li>
  <li>List 5</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.clear{
  display: block;
  float: none;
  clear: both;
  height: 1px;
  line-height: 1px;
  font-size: 1px;
}
```

The   and font declarations will ensure the clearing div is only 1 pixel tall, otherwise it will be the height of the current font size (yay!).

As this is only for IE7, I would keep your markup clean and add in this extra guff dynamically with javascript for just < IE8.

Comment: I'd suggest the use of conditional comments instead of javascript. It's one less dependency to worry about. See http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Comment: I disagree in this case Olly, the fact is you need an extra element for just IE7, for me it's preferable to keep your markup semantic and avoid adding this extra element for all browsers, just insert it for IE7. As long as your JS is well organised the dependency shouldn't be a problem. Removing support for IE7 would just be a case of removing the JS in one place, rather than every occurrence throughout your HTML.

In general though, conditional comments on the HTML element FTW!

Comment: After re-reading your post I agree completely! I stand (sit) corrected :) Of course those conditional classes make it easier to target IE7 (etc) specifically with javascript, so maybe a hybrid approach is the best bet!